# Django template overrides not loading

Tags: python, django

New to Django.

I'm trying to customize the change_form.html template right now. However, Django is simply refusing to load the local one I have created.

My app is listed in INSTALLED_APPS. APP_DIRS is set to True. I even hardcoded an absolute path to a base directory templates folder. At this point I literally have templates in every single possible folder and location Django would look for custom templates overrides. If I alter the base template my change_form and change_list do update. What am I missing here?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'quizzes', # my app
'django.contrib.admin',
#snip


TEMPLATES = [

{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
```

Locations I have the templates already:

/templates (at the same level as manage.py)

/templates/quiz

/templates/quizzes

/online_training/templates (the main project folder)

/quizzes/templates (main app folder)

/quizzes/templates/quiz

/quizzes/templates/quizzes

/quizzes/admin

/quizzes/admin/templates

/quizzes/admin/quizzes

/quizzes/admin/quiz

I'm trying the shotgun approach here, and either I completely missed the correct folder to put this stuff in, or something is jacked.

Comment: If you are running Django with Apache or other server, try restarting it, because many times templates are cached.

Comment: Its running on the dev django server only. Which has been stopped/started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating this structure (in your project root directory):

templates/admin/quizzes/yourmodelname/change_form.html

Comment: Finally! I figured I must be missing the actual appropriate directory, but I spent so much time going crosseyed looking for the right one, I missed it.

This worked, thanks!